# TensorFlow LSTM Iterator for test queue is incremented during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a LSTM in Tensorflow, which uses a queue to distinguish between training and test data.

The structure is as follows:

```
# Queue for Trainingdata
iter_train = tf.data.Dataset.range(epochNum_train).repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

input_train_queue = input_train[:, iter_train * num_steps : (iter_train + 1) * num_steps, :]
input_train_queue.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps, input_size])

output_train_queue = output_train[:, iter_train * num_steps: (iter_train + 1) * num_steps, :]
output_train_queue.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps, input_size])

# Queue for Testdata
iter_test = tf.data.Dataset.range(epochNum_test).repeat().make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

input_test_queue = input_test[:, iter_test * num_steps : (iter_test + 1) * num_steps, :]
input_test_queue.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps, input_size])

output_test_queue = output_test[:, iter_test * num_steps: (iter_test + 1) * num_steps, :]
output_test_queue.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps, input_size])   

# tf.cond for the selection of data
rnn_outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, tf.cond(useTestData, lambda: input_test_queue, lambda: input_train_queue),
                                      dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=init_state)
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(rnn_outputs, tf.cond(useTestData, lambda: output_test_queue, lambda: output_train_queue)))
train_fn = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(error)
```

My problem is that `iter_test` is also incremented when training data is given to the LSTM:

```
t1 = sess.run(iter_test) # t1 has the value 0 
sess.run(train_fn, {useTestData: False})
t2 = sess.run(iter_test) # t2 has the value 2 
t3 = sess.run(iter_test) # t3 has the value 3
```

Why is `iter_test` incremented during training?  And is there a solution to the problem so that `iter_test` is not changed during training?